# use function from index.php like this class->publicF->f()

Tags: php, function, class

guys lets say we have this class: all i want to do is to use a specific function to do something, think it as a button, but in a way that you have 1 public function and you can execute parts of it!

```
CLASS DATA {
      public function X() {
           function A() { 
              //do_something
           }
      }
}
```

and now i'm in the index.php and i want to call the function A() only.
i tried `$data->X()->A()` but nothing
i tried `$data->X(A())` also nothing

is it possible this?

Comment: Read up on fluent interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the way you've written it, no.  Looks to me like you're trying to build something in the way you would a Javascript application.  But like Rizier123 points out you could do something like this.

```
class Foo {
    public function getBar(){
        return new Bar();
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function someFunction() {

    }
}


$foo = new Foo();

$foo->getBar()->someFunction();
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why you would want to nest things that way when inheriting would be a better route.  Something like this:

```
class Foo extends Bar {

}

class Bar {
    public function someFunction() {

    }
}


$foo = new Foo();

$foo->someFunction();
```

But I guess you could use the former as a way to pass specific constructor parameters in a consistent manor.

```
class Foo {
    public function getRainbow(){
        return new Bar('rainbow');
    }
}

class Bar {
    private $type;

    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        switch($this->type){
            case 'rainbow':
                echo 'All the way across the sky.';
                break;
            default:
                echo 'Boring.';
                break;
        }
    }
}


$foo = new Foo();

$foo->getRainbow()->someFunction();
```

Comment: thank you!! i tried to study php, mysql and html with a book a book first.

Comment: it didnt work! now i'm designing my project and everything is  researched first as a tool to use, but i have so many questions because no book is perfect to solve them. if this questions are trash i can always delete them!!

Comment: you see First i want something, Second i think how to do it and Third i ask a question to find the proper tool for the job!

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you get an error?  Or did it just not behave the way you expected.  Either way, update your question with the code you tried and the error/issue you have and maybe I can help you further.

Comment: no it did! but from your explanation i studied "fluent interfaces" and found another way! more elegant, re-expressing this.